# JAX-RPC 1.1 and Holder class

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rpc

I need to create a new web service in Eclipse using File/New/Web Service. I'm using Tomcat 6 and Axis. During creating a new web service I receive following warning:

> The service class "XXX" does not comply to one or more requirements of
>   the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or function
>   correctly. The method "importInternshipData" on the service class
>   "XXX" uses a data type,  "javax.xml.ws.Holder", that is not supported
>   by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize
>   or deserialize correctly.  Loss of data or complete failure of the Web
>   service may result.

One of prams of my web service method is `Holder<CrossSystemAuth> header`. I must use it to authenticate the caller.

Where's the problem? I copied the `header` param from sample implementation. Could you please help me?